# Quickbooks ItemSitesQueryRq version

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

We are running Quickbooks 2013 and we are trying to pull the inventory of our items from all of our locations.

The request we send via the webservice looks as follows:

```
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
<QBXML>
  <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
    <ItemSitesQueryRq requestID="2">
      <ItemSiteFilter>
        <ItemFilter>
          <ListID>800003F3-1299965940</ListID>
        </ItemFilter>
      </ItemSiteFilter>
    </ItemSitesQueryRq>
  </QBXMLMsgsRq>
</QBXML>
```

However we are just getting an error message returned:
"*The version of QBXML that was requested is not supported or is unknown.*"

The ListID is the ID of the product we would like the stock status for (at all our locations).

Any suggestions as to how I can format the request XML will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the message error message says, *the version of QBXML you requested is not supported*.

You are requesting version:

```
<?qbxml version="13.0"?>
```

QuickBooks 2013 supports a maximum of version:

```
12.0
```

So you can either:

a) Upgrade to QuickBooks 2014

OR

b) Request a different qbXML version

Comment: Ah, the good old "staring at the wrong line". Never noticed I had hit 3 instead of 2. Thank you.